# onLoadFinished not called when screen locked

Tags: android, loader

I'have a problem with onLoadFinished method i use it to get contact information from ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds table.

```
 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Log.i("OnCreate", "At onCreateLoader");
    if(id == CALL_ID) {
            return getPhoneNumberLoader(name);
    }else if(id==EMAIL_ID){
            return getEmailAddressLoader(name);
    }
    return null ;
}
```

if screen of mobile is locked it will not call onFinishLoader until unlock screen again

Comment: loaders are for updating UI, why do you need to load data, if there is no UI?

Comment: I need to get  email from contact and send email all these in background

Comment: You should consider using something like `IntentService`